# Will 'list.getStore().remove(record)' in listening disclosure sync the 'list.getData()' in sencha touch 2.1?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I don't use a model in my list.
When the user delete one item in the list with a disclose listener,it dose show being deleted,
but when later when i use Ext.getCmp(listIndex).getData() ,it still shows not being deleted.
Below is the code of the view of list  :

```
{
   xtype: 'list',
   height: '100%',
   id: 'listId',
   style: 　'padding:5px;border:1px solid green;',
   itemTpl: '{Name}',
   disableSelection: true,
   onItemDisclosure: true,
   listeners: 　 {
       disclose: function (list, record, target, index, e, eOpts) {
           console.log(list.getData());
           var deleteFunc = function (buttonId, value, opt) {
               if ('yes' == buttonId) {
                   list.getStore().remove(record);
                   list.getStore().sync(); // seems not working
                   console.log(list.getData());
               }
           };
           Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm', 'are you sure to delete this one ?', deleteFunc);

       },
   }
}
```

Comment: what you mean 'I don't use a model in my list'.. how do you setting data for the list ?..

Comment: @Viswa  I just decode the json data from the server and then set the data array to the list using list.setData();

Comment: @Viswa  i have to much time to learn using MVC pattern..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log(list.getStore().getData()); 

 OR

console.log(Ext.getCmp('listId').getStore().getData());
```

**Note**

`list.getData()` retrives the  initial set of data to apply to the tpl (list itemTpl).